# How can I print to HDMI display on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, gdb, raspbian

I can print debug messages to GDB console with `printf` or `cout`, but none of the data actually shows up on the HDMI display running on /dev/fb0

Is there a way to print data directly out on the display without having to write to /dev/fb0

This is Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspbian Lite OS

The program is supposed to run in the background from `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Have you tried writing to /dev/console ?   If you are getting console messages there that should work, but it isn't entirely clear what mode you are running the HDMI in.  (Note you would typically have to be root or to change the device node's permissions, but that would be the case when run from rc.local)

Comment: Thanks, that worked well, do you want to post that as an answer? I will definitely accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems that you are running <s>the HDMI in a text mode</s> a *framebuffer console* on the HDMI (rather than something like X) and want to print messages to it.

For that purpose in most configurations, you can write to `/dev/console`

Code doing this would need to run as root (as something launched from rc.local would) or the permission of the device node would need to be changed.

You can also typically (as the owner or as root) write to the pty devices for GUI-mode terminals, ssh sessions, etc.

Finally note that there is the unix-style [write](https://linux.die.net/man/1/write) command which would write to a user's terminal session(s).

Comment: Im reading https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md and I cant find anything about "text mode", what setting is this?

Comment: On a pi you are probably in an *effectively* textual mode unless you started X or are running some special direct graphics program.  Do you have text on your screen and no pictorial gui?